# Connect to an MySQL server using MySQL Workbench over SSH

Tags: mysql, ssh, mysql-workbench

I am successfully able to login to a VM over SSH and to the SQL server from the command line.

But when I try to add a connection on MySQL Workbench and using the same credentials, same host (hostname is an IPV4 address), it says

```
Failed to Connect to MySQL at <Ip address>:3306 through SSH tunnel at user@VM with user <username>.
Unable to Connect to localhost.
```

Do anyone have any idea on this issue
I have no mysql installed on my local machine.

Try connecting OVER ssh through commandline and connection was successful. See below

```
ssh user @ <ipaddress of VM>
```

then

```
mysql -h <Mysqlhost> -u < user > -p < database > -A
```

But when I try to do the same via MYSQL workbench, it fails.

Comment: This is hard to diagnose without knowing what you set in your SSH config of mysql workbench. As a high level guidance, you should put your mysql server as the `SSH Hostname` and then use `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` as your `MySQL Hostname`. It will set up a tunnel through SSH and then connect locally to `localhost` which will forward through the tunnel. This is slightly different than how you achieved this through CLI, but it should work fine if you set the values in the config correctly.

Comment: To do similar in your CLI then in one terminal window run: `ssh user@yourmysqlserver -L 3306:localhost:3306` once connected, open a second terminal window and run `mysql -h localhost -u <yourmysqluser> -p <yourpass>`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you fill all the details like shown in the image below.

[image]

The error message  you have posted shows that MySQL Hostname and Username is not filled.